# Exporting from table with multiple pages

Tags: angular

I am using the ngx-export-as module to be able to export data from a table in my angular project. This is working fine, apart from the fact that it only exports the data on the page it is on. How can I get it to export all pages?

Here is the code I am using:

--- HTML TABLE ---

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped border-top-0" id="casesTable">
                <thead class="borderless">
                  <tr>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Case Number' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Subject' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Priority' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Asset Type' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Creation Date' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Last Message' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Status' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'Stage' | translate }}</button></th>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-link table-headers">{{ 'SLA' | translate }}</button></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let case of cases | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
                    <td><a [routerLink]="['/casemgmt/case', case.id]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']">{{ case.casenumber }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ case.title | translate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ case.priority | translate }}</td>
                    <td *ngIf = "case.type === '1'">{{ 'Hardware' | translate }}</td>
                    <td *ngIf = "case.type === '2'">{{ 'Software' | translate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ case.createddate | date: 'MMM d y, h:mm a'}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf = "case.lastmessagedate === ' '"></td>
                    <td *ngIf = "case.lastmessagedate !== ' '">{{ case.lastmessagedate | date: 'MMM d y, h:mm a'}}</td>
                    <td>{{ case.status.text | translate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ case.stage | translate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ case.sla | translate }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr *ngIf="cases && cases.length === 0">
                    <td colspan='9'>{{ 'No results' | translate }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
<div *ngIf="cases.length > 0">
            <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="cases.length" [pageSize]="20" [maxSize]="10" [(page)]="page" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
          </div>
```

--- Component.ts (Only export related stuff) ---

```
import { ExportAsService, ExportAsConfig, SupportedExtensions } from 'ngx-export-as';

config: ExportAsConfig = {
    type: 'pdf',
    elementId: 'casesTable',
    options: {
      jsPDF: {
        orientation: 'landscape'
      },
      pdfCallbackFn: this.pdfCallbackFn
    }
  };

private pdfCallbackFn (pdf) {
    const noOfPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    for (let i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
      pdf.setPage(i);
      pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + noOfPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 100, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 30);
    }
  }

  exportFile(type: SupportedExtensions, opt?: string) {
    this.config.type = type;
    if (opt) {
      this.config.options.jsPDF.orientation = opt;
    }
    this.exportAsService.save(this.config, 'cases').subscribe(() => {});
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: On every page change you are calling api to fatch data or are you getting all the data at once and applied pagination at client side ?

Comment: @Aarsh Getting all the data at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with ngx-export-as library.

Because in this library they are using elementId in the configuration while exporting data
as you can see here `elementId: 'casesTable',`

so when you are exporting in this element only 10 records will be available so only that amount of data can be exported

you have to find such library that passes all the data at once and generate excel or csv but as per my knowledge I don't know that any library will provide that kind of support

because in client side you have to give some element or css to that table so that can be exported

So as per my suggestion you have to create your exported file in back-end and then call your api to fetch the exported file as this is very common scenario and in general we are creating file in back-end not in front-end.
because at a time you get 100 of records and while you are exporting other user upload another record then you will not get that record in your exported sheet so sometimes it will create madness in calculation or etc.

So as per my suggestion move your export code in to back-end that will be much easier.
and if you want to do it in client side then you have to compromise with this much data.